# "who/what should ... but" structure, examples with different tenses?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

Here's an example sentence with that structure:

> I looked under the bed, and what should I find but the keys I lost last week?

Are the following sentences correct in different tenses?

1. I was looking under the bed, and what should I find but the keys I lost last week?
2. I had looked under the bed, and what should have I found but the keys I lost last week?